# error: failed to attach to process ID 3030 ios Share Extension

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I am doing for share extension with Swift and I try to run my share extension. But it can't launch and fail with this error. How shall I do? I don't use default share view and I use custom layout though. If I use default view, at least, it show that view. Now, it doesn't launch my custom view.

```
error: failed to attach to process ID 3030
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exact same error with a keyboard extension for some time. Sometimes it attaches, sometimes it does not.
I think what causes it is the Simulator running (even with no app open in it), while trying to debug the extension on an actual device. Quitting the Simulator seems to have fixed the problem for me.